# Google Maps Grey Squares Apear

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I have search the web for this kind of problem an fixes but with no luck.
My problem is not the all google map grey squares that indecates an api problem 
the problem is that I see part of the map and the other parts are grey 
and its random:  sometimes the map is at the top and the grey spot is down sometime in the left etc.

Comment: here is a pc of thr problem   http://img717.imageshack.us/img717/6827/maprw.png

Comment: Try using the `tilesloaded` event to make sure all your tiles have loaded properly - maybe it's just a problem with the browser rendering the map. Something like, `google.maps.event.addListener(map, "tilesloaded", function() {
        alert("everything good");
});`

Answer (score -1):

I have this a lot, generally on slower internet for some reason. If you check the console log in your browser (Firebug, I believe IE/Chrome/FF have one built in?), there should be some sort of error going on in Google Maps API. I haven't found a reliable programming fix for this - I generally just move the map around a bit and it forced Google to reload the section and it generally works then.