# Google maps loading some, but not all map tiles

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm using Google Maps in an Android app and am having trouble on only one testing device--the Motorola Xoom Family Edition (which, FYI, is a buggy crappy device compared to the other versions of the Xoom).

When I view the map, some map tiles load, others appear as gray. When I zoom or move the map around, a few more tiles may load, but not all. What is strange is that this used to work just fine.

I can see that I'm not the only person with this issue, although this person was using jquery on a website: [Google Maps Grey Squares Apear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612895/google-maps-grey-squares-apear)

Again, only SOME of the tiles do not load. Some tiles load just fine, and the map works just fine on all other devices. I am using the signed APK on all testing devices; the Maps API key is correct on all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research and seeing this log message appear once in a while:

```
07-11 11:32:34.981: W/System.err(9650): IOException processing: 26
07-11 11:32:34.981: W/System.err(9650): java.net.SocketTimeoutException
07-11 11:32:34.981: W/System.err(9650):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:451)
07-11 11:32:34.981: W/System.err(9650):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:75)
07-11 11:32:34.981: W/System.err(9650):     at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
07-11 11:32:34.981: W/System.err(9650):     at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.read(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:134)
07-11 11:32:34.981: W/System.err(9650):     at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:174)
07-11 11:32:34.981: W/System.err(9650):     at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:159)
07-11 11:32:34.981: W/System.err(9650):     at libcore.io.Streams.readFully(Streams.java:47)
07-11 11:32:34.981: W/System.err(9650):     at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:133)
07-11 11:32:34.981: W/System.err(9650):     at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:129)
07-11 11:32:34.981: W/System.err(9650):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readImageData(BaseTileRequest.java:194)
07-11 11:32:34.981: W/System.err(9650):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:124)
07-11 11:32:34.981: W/System.err(9650):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
07-11 11:32:34.981: W/System.err(9650):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
07-11 11:32:34.981: W/System.err(9650):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
07-11 11:32:34.981: W/System.err(9650):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
07-11 11:32:34.981: W/System.err(9650):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)
```

I gather the issue can be related to Internet connectivity; a slow connection may cause some of the tiles to not load successfully. I'm on a high-speed wi-fi connection, but restarted the Motorola Xoom Family Edition and the problem went away.

I don't think there's anything developers can do to solve this problem; it would either be a device problem (as it was with the Xoom F'ed-up Edition) or a poor Internet connection that the user has.Hope this info helps other people running into the same issue.